# Finding out if data-sold-out="false" in html using beautifulsoup

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

```
data-style-name="Gold" data-style-id="20316" data-sold-out="false" data-description="null" alt="Tvywspp25q0" /></a>
<a class="" data-images="
```

this is the html code and im trying to get find if  data-sold-out="false" or true so i can than do something with it. I am wondering how can i find out what data-sold-out id equal to and return it.  I am using python and beautiful soup.

any help appreciated

Comment: can you paste the whole html code and the python code which you tried?

Comment: for sizes in soup.find_all(text='data-sold-out'):
   sizes_in_stock.append(sizes)
   print (sizes_in_stock)

Comment: that is what i tried

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to find any tags with data-sold-out="false" or data-sold-out="true" right?

I think you can do this

```
all_html = bs('<a data-style-name="Gold" data-style-id="20316" data-sold-out="false" data-description="null" alt="Tvywspp25q0" /></a>
<a class="" data-images="">')
a_tag = all_html.findAll(attrs={"data-sold-out": "false"})
```

then you can extract any attribute inside them like this

```
for item in a_tag:
    print(item['data-style-name'])
```